# "Could not find the driver" Error. How to configure PHP with SQL Server in IIS 7?

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, pdo, sqlsrv

I have a PHP website using SQL Server as the database. I want to put it on the windows server. The server using IIS 7. I have a problem to run my website, when I try to login I always get an error :

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
>   could not find driver

I did put the pdo sql driver in my php ext. and I already registered that in php.ini but I still got that error. 

 [image]

And in my phpinfo() I could not find the "sqlsrv" words at all. Do you know why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS for PHP, you should load dlls with nts (non-thread safe) version.

```
php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

Comment: so i have to instal php 56 non thread safe first then put the nts dlls?

Comment: @hendraspt As far as I understand from your explanation on the question, you don't have to do anything with php installation. Just put nts dlls instead of ts dlls (and replace in the ini file). Note: if you have 64 bit php, those 5.6 version dlls won't work, too.